# Express js installation error in node

Tags: node.js, express, npm

While trying to install express js by the command "npm install -g express" in cmd prompt in windows it shows the following error

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\chapter3\sample-app\web-server.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

How to fix this and run a web server?

Comment: Are you sure ? You would get this error because you are running this file `D:\chapter3\sample-app\web-server.js`, without isntalling express.

Comment: @user568109 yes :) . but now i fixed by reinstalling express in node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't install express globally. `cd` into your project directory, then `npm install express`.

Global package install is meant to install command line utilities; project dependencies should be installed locally, see [npm's FAQ](https://npmjs.org/doc/faq.html#I-installed-something-globally-but-I-can-t-require-it) and [this blog post](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/).

Comment: The biggest misconception with node and npm: "A global install can be used for installing a package, which can then be `require`d anywhere"